# Lambda notation - Trying to refactor but getting issues

Tags: java, playframework, lambda, java-8

I have a number of methods that are mapped to server requests. The requests use [promises](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/index.html) (from Play Framework) to return responses some time in the future. Here is an example of one of my actions:

```
public static Promise<Result> someAction() {
    MyBean data = new MyBean(getData(request().body()));
    Promise<MyReq> promise = Promise.promise(() -> new MyReq(data));
    return promise.map((MyReq req) -> ok(req.getResponse()));
}
```

Note that `MyReq` extends `MyAbstractReq<T>`.

What I was hoping to do was to be able to take all of the common code out of all the action methods and bundle it into a single common `handleRequest` method. However I struggle to understand Lambda Notation and cannot modify the code to suit my purposes.

I understand that `() -> new MyReq(data)` basically means `(arg1, arg2, ...) -> { body }` which can be written like (I think):

```
MyBean data = new MyBean(getData(request().body()));

// Anonymous Functional Interface
MyFunction f = new MyFunction() {      
    @Override
    public void getReq(){
        return new MyReq(data);
    }
};
```

Or something like that.

But what I am trying to achieve is this something like this (doesn't compile but I hope it gives enough of an idea what I'm trying to achieve):

```
public static Promise<Result> handleRequest(MyAbstractReq<?> req) {
    Promise<MyAbstractReq<?>> promise = Promise.promise(() -> req);
    return promise.map(() -> ok(req.getResponse()));
}
```

And each action looks like this:

```
public static Promise<Result> someAction() {
    MyBean data = new MyBean(getData(request().body()));
    return handleRequest(new MyReq(data));
}
```

Can someone please point out what it is that I am missing with regards to Lambda notation and explain how I can achieve what I am trying to do.

**Update**

The error I get is

> `Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method apply(? super MyAbstractReq<?>)`

I was guessing that that was because the syntax was incorrect, it was just my first naive attempt to refactor it.

The `req.getResponse()` method is not really relevant as it just generates a Json object (ObjectNode - Jackson faster xml) which can be consumed by the `ok()` method to create a `Result`

**Update 2**

With regards to using `handleRequest(MyAbstractReq<T> req)` I initially actually had this but the error was basically the same.

> `Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method apply(? super MyAbstractReq<T>)`

**Update 3**

I beg your pardon. The error is on the line `return promise.map(() -> ok(req.getResponse()));`

**Update 4**

I probably should have mentioned that I know how to solve the issue by changing the `handleRequest()` method to:

```
public static Promise<Result> handleRequest(MyAbstractReq<?> req) {
    Promise<MyAbstractReq<?>> promise = Promise.promise(() -> req);
    return promise.map((MyAbstractReq<?> notUsed) -> ok(req.getResponse()));
}
```

But it feels wrong as the line `return promise.map((MyAbstractReq<?> notUsed) -> ok(req.getResponse()));` takes an argument of `MyAbstractReq<?>` which is never used.

I don't understand enough about the notation of Lambda expressions to tell if this is not the best way to achieve what I want (I didn't mention it as I wanted to see what people's suggestions would be without me leading them to an answer).

Comment: What is the issue? Is there any error? Where is your `getResponse()` method defined?

Comment: I updated the question to address your comments. With regards to what it has to do with Lambda expressions, I am trying to refactor Lambda expressions but I do not know how to. The errors indicate that there is an error in the "Lambda expression's signature".

Comment: If my question is unclear then I'd appreciate it if you could tell me which parts you don't understand so that I could clarify.

Comment: @Neilos You're using the wrong variable to get response in lamdba. It should be `notUsed.getResponse()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your initial code

```
public static Promise<Result> someAction() {
    MyBean data = new MyBean(getData(request().body()));
    Promise<MyReq> promise = Promise.promise(() -> new MyReq(data));
    return promise.map((MyReq req) -> ok(req.getResponse()));
}
```

everything works as intended as `map` gets a function which specifies how to process the argument `req`. But in your refactored code you are suddenly attempting to access a variable from the outer scope instead of keeping the logic:

```
public static Promise<Result> handleRequest(MyAbstractReq<?> req) {
    Promise<MyAbstractReq<?>> promise = Promise.promise(() -> req);
    // the following function refers to handleRequest’s parameter instead of its argument
    return promise.map((MyAbstractReq<?> notUsed) -> ok(req.getResponse()));
}
```

This works in this special case but is indeed as wrong as your feeling tells you.

Just stay with the original logic here:

```
public static Promise<Result> handleRequest(MyAbstractReq<?> req) {
    Promise<MyAbstractReq<?>> promise = Promise.promise(() -> req);
    // arg is unrelated to req here though both variables happen to have to same contents
    return promise.map(arg -> ok(arg.getResponse()));
}
```

but it is still a bit strange as the promise is constructed around an already existing object instead of constructing it. Maybe you want

```
public static Promise<Result> handleRequest(Function0<MyAbstractReq<?>> supplier) {
    Promise<MyAbstractReq<?>> promise = Promise.promise(supplier);
    return promise.map(arg -> ok(arg.getResponse()));
}
```

so you can call it like

```
handleRequest( ()-> new MyReq(new MyBean(getData(request().body()))) );
```

as then the `Promise` will really cover the entire operation.

Comment: "arg is unrelated to req here though both variables happen to have to same contents" I'm not sure I get why this is the case. Is it because I pass `req` to promise and then when `promise.map` is called it uses the value of `req` and passes it as the arg to the function? But this would make then the same object. Is it a copy or something?

Comment: "as then the Promise will really cover the entire operation" I did wonder if the object creation should be in the promise as opposed to before. I think that this point is actually where the whole issue arose for me when I changed it to happen before (I didn't really know how to do it otherwise). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The argument of the mapping function will contain a *copy of the reference* returned by the supplier function, thus it points to the same object instance. So it’s the same object but the choice of variable makes a huge semantic difference as `arg -> ok(arg.getResponse())` is a function which works on its argument while `notUsed -> ok(req.getResponse())` is a function which works on an unrelated object captured on lambda instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

Now after your update 2, you've come up with following method:

```
public static Promise<Result> handleRequest(MyAbstractReq<?> req) {=
    Promise<MyAbstractReq<?>> promise = Promise.promise(() -> req);
    return promise.map((MyAbstractReq<?> notUsed) -> ok(req.getResponse()));
}
```

Before proceeding further, let me explain what `map()` does. On a given `Iterable`, when applied, `map()` will simply transform each element to something else (which might be something extracted out of the element). For this, we pass a `Function` to the `map()` method, which takes an input and returns an output.

In this case, `(MyAbstractReq<?> notUsed) -> ok(req.getResponse())` is that function. You take `notUsed` as argument (which is one element from `promise`, and call `ok()` method on response of that object.

But you see, you're not using the argument you passed, but a different object (the one you passed as argument to `handleRequest()` method. That is wrong. You should use `notUsed.getResponse()` there.

Also, you don't need to give type of `notUsed` there. Java can infer the type. So, change your method to:

```
public static Promise<Result> handleRequest(MyAbstractReq<?> req) {=
    Promise<MyAbstractReq<?>> promise = Promise.promise(() -> req);
    return promise.map(promReq -> ok(promReq.getResponse()));
}
```

Comment: What I don't get is how `req` and `promReq` contain the same data... are they the same object just stored as a reference inside the promise?

Comment: @Neilos That would depend upon what `Promise.promise()` method does. It takes a function which just returns the `req` you passed. Now what it does with `req`, I don't know. If  it doesn't create new object, then yes both `req` and `promReq` references point to same object.